# Is GNU Solfege viable?

Tags: sound

Wanting to have GNU Solfege functional on my 20.04 Ubuntu Studio box...   it comes with the distro, but doesn't seem to be maintained, so I would like to get it to work or get it removed from the distro (or help get it in a supported status).

Doesn't seem to have functioned well in any recent versions of Ubuntu Studio, but I didn't note at what point it had ceased to function.   I use Jack, and generally have been successful in getting everything working through that over the years, but happy to shutdown or elide Jack for a Solfege session.

So, getting no sound from Solfege :)  In the "Sound Setup" section of Solfege, there are three enablement options:

1. default seems to be "Use external MIDI player", with a Test button.  No luck there, and have tried with any number of soft synths, and soft mixers (QAS, Jack connections, whatever), to figure out how this is routed.
2. "Use ALSA device", which states "Disabled because the pyalsa Python module was not found", which I have tried to remedy, but I essentially found that pyalsa is not available for Python 3.
3. "Use OSS device", which is not generally created (my prime option is "/dev/music"), and when I select that, I get the error "cannot import name '_solfege_c_midi' from 'solfege.soundcard' (/usr/share/solfege/solfege/soundcard/**init**.py)"

So, does this work for anyone at this level?   Maybe I should try with a backlevel VM, but that's a lot of work.   And not sure of a reasonable replacement for Solfege...  it was nice and extensible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working on xubuntu 20.04, with default setting:  external midi (timidity).
It is played via   pulseaudio, as seen in "pulseaudio volume control"  .
Check timidity  running :
`timidity any_midi_file.mid`
Possible problem would be pulseaudio unavailable for some reason.

Comment: Yes, you hit it.  I'm investigating a different issue regarding timidity, so I ran a midi file as you mentioned, and saw in the pulseaudio control (pavucontrol) that an entry under "Playback" appeared as libao[timidity].  I rerouted it to the jack sink, and I had sound!  Now when I use Solfege, I have sound.  I see that the entry only shows up in pulseaudio control while it's running, for example, when you have solfege play an interval.... so if you don't have it open and it front of you, you won't see it.  Sigh.  Thanks again!